# What will happen if my kubernetes Pod has a one unhealthy container out of four containers?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

What will happen if my kubernetes Pod has a one unhealthy container out of four containers?

Will my Pod still treated as a healthy Pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my previous answer, a pod can't go to ready state if any container of that pod is not ready whatever reason is it.

Answer (score 1):

no, if any readinessProbe fails, the whole pod is not ready